# Meaning of the phrase "the derivative is independent of the differential"

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, math-history

I was trying to read Riemann's "Foundations for a general theory of functions of a complex variable" and very early on ran into the phrase.

> A complex variable $w$ is said to be a function of another complex variable $z$, if $w$ varies with $z$ in such a way that the value of the derivative $\frac{dw}{dz}$ is independent of the value of the differential $dz$.

I haven't a clue what this might mean.

Comment: He is saying that, in order to treat the function $f(z)$ of a complex variable $z=x+iy$ as a function of a single variable, we must have that the expression $\dfrac {df} {dz}$ must make sense, i.e. $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \dfrac {f(z+\delta)-f(z)} {\delta}$ must be independent of the "direction" in which $\delta$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riemann is most likely not thinking of the differential $dz$ as *tending* anywhere, but rather adopting a Leibnizian attitude whereby one assigns an infinitesimal value to the $dz$, computes the corresponding change in $w$, forms a quotient and uses the [law of homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_law_of_homogeneity) to attribute an *assignable* value to it. Then "being independent of the differential" is understood quite literally.